# searching through and adding to an alphabetized list

Tags: c#, list, search

My database consists of a csv file.  I want to keep it alphabetized by the first column, so that when searching I can stop when I've gone past where the search item would be found in the list.

The setup: I've read the entire csv file into a `List<string>` called fullDB, and I have a search string called itemToFind.  Here is my search code:

```
public string[] isFoundInDB(List<string> fullDB, string itemToFind)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fullDB.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] line = fullDB[i].Split(',');

        if (itemToFind.CompareTo(line[0]) < 0)
        {
            return new string[] { "-1", i.ToString(), "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1" }; //not found
        }

        if (line[0] == itemToFind)
        {
            return new string[] { i.ToString(), line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4] };
        }
    }

    return new string[] { "-1", fullDB.Count.ToString(), "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1" }; //not found
}
```

So this will either give me the index where it was found in the database OR it will give me the index where the itemToFind went past where it would be alphabetically.  If it's found, I modify the values that are there.  If it's not found, I insert it at the correct place alphabetically using `List.Insert`

My question is, in the event that itemToFind is NOT found in the database, would it be more efficient to do my current `List.Insert`, OR do a `List.Add`, then sort the entire thing when I'm done adding things?  I would likely use this code to sort the entire database:

```
IEnumerable<string> query =
    from line in fullDB
    let x = line.Split(',')
    orderby x[0]
    select x[0] + "," + x[1] + "," + x[2] + "," + x[3] + "," + x[4];

fullDB = query.ToList();
```

Or is there another, better way?

Using C#, .NET framework 4.0

Comment: If your code works it would probably be better to ask on codereview.stackexchange.com though double check before asking there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a SortedDictionary with the first column as a key:

```
List<string> lines = ... // read csv file

SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedLines = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
    sortedLines[fields[0]] = line;
}
```

Then you'll be able to do an O(log n) search:

```
string foundLine;
if (sortedLines.TryGetValue(itemToFind, out foundLine))
{
    ... // handle the found line
}
else
{
    // add a new line:
    string newLine = // ...
    sortedLines.Add(itemToFind, newLine);
}
```

If the first column is not unique you may use:

```
SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment.  This worked perfectly and is very fast.  Thanks!